Excel, use of function FILTERXML in data obtained from WEBSERVICE function
I use KRAKEN, throw their API ("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=BTCEUR) & WEBSERVICE function I can take data by syntax:
Request=WEBSERVICE("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=BTCEUR")
it will take data into XML format:\ XML``{ "error": [], "result": { "BTCEUR": { "a":[ "30300.10000", "1", "1.000"], "b":[ "30300.00000", "1", "1.000"], "c": ["30303.9900", "0.00067643"], "v":[ "4083.67001100", "4412.73601799"], "p":["30706.77771","30689.13205"], "t":[ 34619,38907], "l":["29868.30000", "29868.30000"], "h":[ "31631.00000", "31631.00000"], "o": "30502.80000" } } } 
I would like to use function FILTERXML to parse DATA from C and 1 = "30303.9900"
I try to use:
excel function=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=BTCEUR"); "//result/BTCEUR/c(1)")
OR
next one=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=BTCEUR"); "//c:[1]")
but EXCEL just return me #VALUE!
Can you help me, please.
I expecting return me a actual price of cryptocurrency, in this case (BTCEUR) which is stored in C and 1 = "30303.9900" (of course, value change every second)

Response to your request is JSON not XML thus FILTERXML can't be used.
Try something like:
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(WEBSERVICE("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=BTCEUR"),"c"":["""),"""")


Great-thank you, its working. Can I with this also similar combination also display value for C-2? ("0.00067643")

=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(WEBSERVICE("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=BTCEUR"),"""],""v"""),",""",-1)

Great, you are so pedant and precise, thanx.
